# Properties of Class Properties of Model not binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**EDIT**

This question had to be edited in some points due to the new findings after some help of **John H** putting me in the right direction in understanding this problem.

**END OF EDIT**

I have these **Models**:

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public SearchModel()
    {
        Filters = new SearchFiltersModel();
    }

    [Display( ... )]
    public string Field1 { get; set; }

    public SearchFiltersModel Filters { get; set; };
}

public class SearchFiltersModel
{
    [Display( ... )]
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the **View**:

```
@model SearchModel

@using ( Html.BeginForm( ... ) )
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.Field1, null, new { @class = "form-control" } )
    @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.Filters.Field2, null, new { @class = "form-control" } )
    (...)
}
```

I can see in the generated HTML:

1. Field1 is rendered with "Field1" in both id and name attributes.
2. Field2 is rendered with "Filters_Field2" in both id attribute and "Filters.Field2" in name attribute (note that one uses underscore and the other uses a dot as separator).

Now, I wrote some values in Field1 and Field2 ("123" and "456", respectively).

Then I clicked the Submit button.

**EDIT**

I should add that this Submit button is not a regular submit button: it's a button that executes a javascript function that collects the fields, then send them AJAX'ly, as we are using https://datatables.net/:

```
    $("#Search_Execute").click(() => {

        table.destroy();

        config.ajax = {
            url: "@Url.Action( ... )",
            type: "POST",
            data: function (d) {
                d.Field1 = $("#Field1").val();
                d.Filters_Field2 = $("#Filters_Field2").val();
            }
        };

        table = $("...").DataTable(config);
```

Note that I wrote d.Filters_Field2 instead of d.Filters.Field2. If I change the underscore to a dot, I will need to add...

```
        d.Filters = new Object();
```

...before setting d.Filters.Field2. It won't work too (see below).

**END OF EDIT**

I could see (e.g. using Chrome's Developer Tools -> Network) the values being POST'ed this way:

1. Field1: 123
2. Filters_Field2: 456

**EDIT**

If I use the object-oriented alternative of Filters.Field2 mentioned above, POST will appear like this:

1. Field1: 123
2. Filters[Field2]:

So, that alternative not only continues doing it wrong (see below!) but it also leaves the field empty.

**END OF EDIT**

So far, it seemed to be working: I fill values in the inputs, they are POST'ed.

Then, in the **Controller\Action**, which signature is, btw:

```
    public ActionResult Search( SearchModel model )
    {
        (...)
    }
```

I added a watch to the model parameter and saw that:

1. model.Field1 is filled with "123".
2. model.Filters.Field2 is empty.

**EDIT**

Before John H comment, at this point, I was wondering the problem was on the POST to Model binding side.

After examining John H's solution I understood that the problem was in the javascript AJAX call rendering the POST's key name the wrong way (it must be Filter.Field2, not Filter_Field2).

So the question below was refactored to:

**END OF EDIT**

==> **How can I effectively POST a Filters.Field2 field using javascript and have it binding correclty to Filters.Field2 in the Model?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

I've never used https://datatables.net before, but it looks to me like you just need to change how you're sending the data in the AJAX call. Something like:

```
var model = {
    Field1: $("#Field1").val(),
    Filters: {
        Field2: $("#Filters_Field2").val()
    }
};

config.ajax = {
    url: "@Url.Action( ... )",
    type: "POST",
    data: model
};
```

`public` fields cannot be used for model binding. You need to use a property instead:

```
public class SearchModel
{
    [Display( ... )]
    public string Field1 { get; set; }

    public SearchFiltersModel Filters { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You're right, my fault. I already changed the code in the question so that it is now a property, not a regular field. The problem continues to happen (model properties OK, properties of model properties, NOK.

Comment: @RuiMiguelPinheiro It works perfectly for me with your code. I've [uploaded a project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/al418dl80gjoqi6/52210258.zip?dl=0) to DropBox for you to look at. Restore the nuget packages, build it and give it a try.

Comment: your solution helped understanding the cause of the problem! I will need to update again the question, as the problem continues, but now the cause is narrowed. There's something I need to add to the question, that I thought was unneeded, but now I see it's important. I'm not submitting using a submit button, but using javascript (AJAX call to update only the results table). And the javascript I'm using is building the POST key-value pairs the wrong way: it should be Filters.Field2 but is being sent as Filters_Field2 (as I wrote in the question). That is causing the binding to fail.

Comment: I saw your suggestion for the javascript. I was already tried many syntax formats, including this one. With your suggestion, in the POST, Field2 cames empty and rendered as Filters[Field2] instead of the correct Filters.Field2. The problem now is what is the right syntax.

Comment: @RuiMiguelPinheiro I've added a second suggestion. Perhaps that will help.

Comment: Same, still rendering Filters[Field2]. :(

Comment: @RuiMiguelPinheiro Tried another. :D

Comment: @RuiMiguelPinheiro If that still doesn't work, I think it would be worth googling for something specific about POSTing objects using datatables. I did see [this](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/post.html), but I'm guessing you've already seen that.

Comment: Wait, wait! It worked! Not the third, but the second (I did a typo when converting your example in my "real" code), now that I fixed it, it worked! Remove the stringify part please so that I can mark it as accepted! :D

Comment: @RuiMiguelPinheiro Brilliant! I've made the change. I'm glad it's fixed for you. :)